# Adding layout views from an xml file to the content view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view

As a bit of background on this - I created a layout for a user interface that sat ontop of a GLSurfaceview. As I progressed I wanted to add adverts from admob on top of the GLSurfaceview. After some reading it seemed like the only way to do this was to create a new Layout view then add each dynamically created view to this. Then set the new Layout view as the content view. This means that all the views in my UI are dynamically created in java code.

My question is:

Is there any way you can use a view from an xml layout that is not set as the content view and somehow add it to the content view just like you would when dynamically creating a view?

I did try this but got null pointer exceptions from which ever view I tried to findViewById.

Any sort of write up explaining this would be helpful

EDIT added code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create an ad.
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);


    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice("******************************").build();

    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);



    final TextView Score = new TextView(this);
    Score.setText(" 0");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams scoreParams = new 
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
    Score.setLayoutParams(scoreParams);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"Fonts/BOYCOTT_.ttf");       
    Score.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
    Score.setTypeface(tf);
    Score.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);     

    // Check if the system supports OpenGL ES 2.0.
    final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final ConfigurationInfo configurationInfo = activityManager.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
    final boolean supportsEs2 = configurationInfo.reqGlEsVersion >= 0x20000;

    if (supportsEs2)
    {

        // Request an OpenGL ES 2.0 compatible context.
        mGLSurfaceView = new RBGLSurfaceView(this); new GLSurfaceView(this);
        mGLSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);           
        final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);          

        mGoogleApiClient = getApiClient();
        mGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(new RBRenderer(this, Score, mGoogleApiClient),displayMetrics);

        layout.addView(mGLSurfaceView);
        layout.addView(Score, scoreParams);
        layout.addView(adView, adParams);
        //Set main renderer             
        setContentView(layout);

    }
    else
    {
        // This is where you could create an OpenGL ES 1.x compatible
        // renderer if you wanted to support both ES 1 and ES 2.
        return;
    }   

}
```

Ok so the above code is creating an adview, textview and surface view and adding them to the layout which is then getting set as the contentview - works great.
But is it possible to add the text view from an xml layout even if this xml layout is not set as the contentview?

Doing this doesnt work

```
 final TextView test= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
 // set properties here etc
 layout.adView(test);
```

because 'test' is null because the layout in which the view 'test' belongs to is not the set as the content view.

Comment: Post the code that isn't working.

Comment: @Eoin i have added code to make the question clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to add the text view from an xml layout even if this xml layout is not set as the contentview?

Yes, it's totally possible! Try this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(this.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View textView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_view, null);
layout.addView(textView);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: can this be used with buttons as well?

Comment: ahh i think i see, with this you are adding the full layout not a view at a time?

Comment: @Rob85 Yes, it can be used with any xml layouts/views. As to the second comment, that depends on the xml resource; it could contain one view or several, but the functionality will be the same. `LayoutInflater.inflate()` returns the root element.